# Two normed spaces are equivalent?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

> If $E,F$ are normed spaces and $T,S : E → F$ are bounded linear mappings
> that coincide on the dense linear subspace $E_0 ⊆ E$, then $T = S$.

Does *coincide on the dense linear subspace* $E_0$ mean that they are equivalent on that dense subspace? And now I have to show that this equivalence can be extrapolated to $T$ being equal to $S$?

Edit:

Because E0 is dense:

$\overline{E_0} := \{ x \in E_0 ~ | ~\exists (x_n): x_n \to x \}$

$\overline{E_0} = E$

This means all points $x\in E$ can be approximated with a sequence from $E_0$. And this means, because $T(x) = S(x) ~\forall x \in E_0$ is sufficient to show that $T(x) = S(x) ~\forall x \in E$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. It means $T(v)=S(v)$ for all $v\in E_0.$

Comment: @D.Brogan Do you have a hint how to prove this?

Comment: They are not "equivalent". They are "equal". And it's not the normed spaces, it is the **mappings** that are equal. The normed spaces are passive characters here.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro What do you think about my "proof"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"coincide on the dense linear subspace $E_0$" does in fact imply that $T = S$. Your notion of "extrapolation" (aka. completion) is correct but your proof omits the fact that $T, S$ are bounded linear mappings, which means they are **uniformly continuous**. Therefore $\forall e \in E,\,\; \exists (e_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \subset E_0 / e_n \to e$. Because they coincide on that dense subspace $E_0$:
$$
T(e_n) = S(e_n) \to T(e) = S(e)
$$
(this last equality wouldn't be true if $T, S$ weren't continuous)

This proof of uniqueness is normally accompanied with a proof of existence. Namely that given a metric space $E_0$ dense in $E$, a complete metric space $Y$, and a function $f: E_0 \to Y$ there exists a unique $g: E \to Y$ that coincides with $f$ on $E_0$.